# Webpack not updating on Heroku rebuild

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, webpack

I have a Node app which builds React with Webpack and is hosted on Heroku.  Whenever I push a newer version to Heroku master, the React files do not update.  I have now pushed several newer versions but the React files in `webpack://` will not update and remain the originals from when I first deployed the app.

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
 entry: {
  main: `${__dirname}/src/app.js`
 },
 output: {
  path: __dirname,
  filename: './public/bundle.js'
 },
 module: {
  loaders: [{
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
    },
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
  }]
 },
 devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
};
```

My `package.json` includes `"heroku-postinstall": "webpack -p -w --config ./webpack.config.js --progress"`.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you are trying to say? Whether react files are not updated on heroku or the webpack config file.

Comment: The React files which are supposed to be rebuilt (with Weback) on each `heroku-postinstall` are not being rebuilt, and thus - although i have uploaded several never versions of the file - the original version persists.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue. 
(Just make sure that your webpack config file is correct and does not have any errors while running the webpack build locally)

I modified my `post-install` script in following way inside my `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf public/bundle.*",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./webpack.prod.config.js --progress --colors",
    "postinstall": "npm run clean && npm run build",
}
```

When I push my changes to heroku `"postinstall"` gets called and it perform to task one after another

1. clean old build files
2. generate new build

In this way old files gets deleted from cache.

but there are are few dependencies which you need to install
[rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf)

```
npm install --save rimraf
```

You can choose any other alternative to "rimraf" as well.